# Content page prior to login screen?

Tags: usability, information-architecture, best-practice

**Context**

We have been asked by a client to have a precursor page to house some content about product and services before the login screen. As our product is B2B SaaS proposition users/employees have no choice but to login to our service to make use of the services we offer.

Traditionally, our end users are sent a url and login credentials to log into our website. In contrast, consumer-facing websites do need to entice users to sign-up so exposing some content prior to login helps achieve that.

So my question is:

**Is it a good idea to have a content page prior to login? What purpose could this page serve?**

---

From a UX perspective, I think **the pros** could be:

1. Providing users with good idea about products and services and therefore set expectations correctly.
2. Content could Help with on boarding (users are not simply catapulted into the homepage) and provided with introductory content where relevant

On **the downside**:

Competitors will know more about our client’s products and services

**What other considerations should I be taking into account?**

Happy to provide more details/ clarifications if needed.

Comment: Won't users just bookmark the *actual* login page and use that every other time they visit instead of going through the interstitial page each time?

Comment: For the downside - can your competitors not just create an account to see your products and services anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Showing a separate content page prior to login is probably going to get ignored.  I know I probably would ignore it.

Here is one example that may accomplish your goal well.  I would keep the content simple and high-level with no more than three bullet points if you are going to use any.  Keep the page load time as low as possible since retaining current customers might be a key priority.

[image: http://themeforest.net/item/moist-single-product-ecommerce-website-template/14387314]

(Disclaimer: I am not the [author](http://themeforest.net/item/moist-single-product-ecommerce-website-template/14387314) and have no relationship with them).

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/analytics/

Note the existing sign-in, while also providing a wealth of info on the service. You can still have a separate "dedicated to sign in" page, but there's no reason you can't marry the two for your home page.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost a clearly stated purpose for this precursor screen must be agreed upon and formalized.

If it's to present information to members (those to authorized to login) *and* non-members then it might make sense.

If it's to present information only to members then as you've pointed to the content must be edited/censored to not reveal privileged info. This could be problematic and/or resource consuming (the exposed content would need to be vetted by someone that knows what can and can't be released publicly). What are the arguments against putting this info immediately *behind* the login barrier?

If it's to expose information mainly to non-members, perhaps this isn't the best place to put it, saddling members with an extra step to get by info that doesn't apply to them.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend an split page design. One side can have the content (with scroll if required) and the other the login info.

Provided the legal team approves the content shown is ok to be seen by public. With just a link i am not sure if it can be protected

The advantages being

1. Save the user time and one step
2. Don't have to force the user to go through the content which will improve the customer satisfaction.